# Is it possible to query the twitter timestamp which is actually stored in Varchar field?

Tags: c#, mysql, twitter

I extracted tweets from twitter streaming api and stored all the Timestamp (of tweets) in the MySQL varchar field. Now, I would want to extract all the tweets for the last one hour. Is it possible to query the database and fetch the results accordingly?

I extracted around 500,000+ tweets and I am not sure if I would be able to change the type of the field and still safeguard all the values.

Time format which I saved in varchar field: `'Wed Oct 10 16:29:56 +0000 2012'`

Comment: At least you learned why date related information is saved into `datetime` type of field :)

Comment: You should just write a script to convert this column to `datetime` and insert everything into a new table.  It will help you in the long run, because the query will run much faster (especially if you index the column).

Comment: damage is already done. Is there a workaround?

Comment: There is, @jalynn2 answered it, however fix the damage rather than going with workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the STR_TO_DATE function as you select the rows to convert the date column into something you can compare. But if you are keeping this data for the long term, you should convert the type of the column to datetime, which would entail moving the data to another table.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to safely move all the data from the old table to the new one?. By the way, I am using C#.

Comment: Create the new table, with the  time column specified. Then you can INSERT INTO new_table(col1, col2, time) SELECT col1, col2, STR_TO_DATE("<format>",strtime) from old_table

Comment: I am not able to create format for this time stamp 'Wed Oct 10 16:29:56 +0000 2012'. Can you please look into it?

Comment: Try this:  '%a %b %e %T %Y' I don't see a format character for the time zone offset. If that format doesn't work, try STR_TO_DATE('%a %b %e %T %Y',REPLACE(colname,' +0000','')). But be aware that your times are being stored in UTC time zone.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [str_to_date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) for your select criteria.

You should convert that field to DATETIME though. Even if str_to_date works the performance is going to be horrifying. :)